# Getting Error - Unhandled exception was thrown by the sandboxed code wrapper

Tags: 2010, sandbox-solution, typeloadexception

I am getting this error after copying and pasting the code from the link below

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms490609%28office.12%29.aspx

It looks like the code cannot load IFilterValues

> [TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.IFilterValues' from assembly 'Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.900.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c'.]

I think the version number (14.900.0.0) is wrong and it should be (14.0.0.0)?

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Have you included the assembly reference properly in your project?

Comment: Yes, I have added the correct reference to Microsoft.SharePoint assembly (version = 14.0.0.0)

Comment: Are you trying to do this as a sandboxed web part as you said in your other post - its a VERY key detail!

Comment: Yes. I believe this is a sandboxed Web Part